# How to remove separator icon for last array map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of strings that I want to render in a way that's one after the other with arrows in between as separators.

`const folders = ["Folder 1", "Folder 2"]`

So I tried the following code :

```
<div style={{display: "flex"}}>
   {folders.map(folder => (
     <p><i className='fa fa-folder'></i> {folder} <i className="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></p>
   ))}
</div>
```

What this does it put that arrow icon after every folder but i don't want it to put that arrow after the last folder. How do I fix?

Comment: Map can take a second argument for index. `folders.map((folder, index) =>...` use the index to check if it is the last element to skip adding the arrow icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can have access to the index of item of the array in which you are performing a map

```
<div style={{display: "flex"}}>
    {folders.map((folder, index) => {
        return (
            <p key={index}>
                <i className='fa fa-folder'></i> 
                {folder} 
                {index !== folders.length - 1 ? <i className="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>: null}
            </p>
         )
        );
    })}
</div>
```

As you can see I add a line which check if the current index in the map is equal to the length of the `folders` and if is not the case the closing chevron is display otherwise it is not display.

Comment: it is good practice to use `!==` instead `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<div style={{display: "flex"}}>
  {folders.map((folder, key) => (
   <p><i className='fa fa-folder'></i> {folder} 
   {index !== (folders.length - 1) ?  <i className="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> : ''} </p>
 ))}
</div>
```

Comment: `v-if` is part of vuejs and not reactjs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` parameter of the `map` function e.g.

```
<div style={{display: "flex"}}>
   {folders.map((folder, index) => (
     <p><i className='fa fa-folder'></i> {folder} 
     {index < folders.length -1 && <i className="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>}
</p>
   ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of index and array length.

```
<div style={{display: "flex"}}>
   {folders.map((folder, index) => (
     <p><i className='fa fa-folder'></i> {folder} {folders.length-1 !== index && <i className="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>}</p>
   ))}
</div>
```